# How to call a getter and setter from a class into another class in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, variables, getter-setter

How do I call a getter and setter from a class to another? I have to call out to another class named StartGame.cs from Ball.cs. I need to put it in a timer in StartGame.cs. For an example, in class Ball.

```
public class Ball
{
    public int speedX { get; private set; }
    public int speedY { get; private set; }
    public int positionX { get; private set; }
    public int positionY { get; private set; }

    public Ball(int speedX, int speedY, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public int setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
    {
        speedX = newSpeedX;
        return newSpeedX;
    }

    public int setSpeedY(int newSpeedY)
    {
        speedY = newSpeedY;
        return newSpeedY;
    }

    public int setPositionX(int newPositionX)
    {
        positionX = newPositionX;
        return newPositionX;
    }

    public int setPositionY(int newPositionY)
    {
        positionY = newPositionY;
        return newPositionY;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Maybe explain it by example.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you're trying to do. You are inside an instance of `StartGame` where you have an instance of `Ball` and for example want to set the `speedX` property of that instance?

Comment: I have many balls in StartGame.cs. Therefore, I am creating a class named Ball.cs. Where, Ball.cs creates the method. And, I will set the speed and position of the ball in StartGame.cs using Ball.cs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable in a different class, that variable will have to be defined as public (or protected/protected internal if you're inheriting from the other class).

Exposing your variables like that means exposing the implementation of your class, though. It's best to abstract that stuff and expose the variable via a property using the get and set accessors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call variable from other class in C# then just

```
Console.WriteLine(test.address);
```

Note one thing that it should be `public` like

```
public class test
{
   public static string address= "";
}
```

Here is a small description about how to call, Hope you understand and modify according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
class StartGame
{
    void MyMethod()
    {
        Ball myBall = new Ball(0, 1, 2, 3);

        int speedX = myBall.speedX;       // == 0
        int speedY = myBall.speedY;       // == 1
        int positionX = myBall.positionX; // == 2
        int positionY = myBall.positionY; // == 3
    }
}
```

Since those fields have private setters, the following would be impossible:

```
myBall.speedX = speedX;
```

Because the setter is not accessible.
However, you do have public setter methods:

```
myBall.setSpeedX(speedX); // this would work
```

...
Honestly, I'm confused... Did you copy-paste this code from somewhere and just don't know how to use it?
I'm fairly certain, anyone who could write this code wouldn't need to ask such a basic question. If I misunderstood your question, I'll just delete this answer.

Comment: I got the above codes from one of the user in stackoverflow as he answered my query. However, I could not figure it out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also write it as a field:

```
private String somevar;

public String Somevar{
 get{ return this.somevar}
 set { this.somevar = value}
}
```